# Zend Tutorial: Difficult to find row 1

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to follow the tutorial https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

I have the problem, that i can't use the getAlbum(1) function.
It is possible to `fetchAll()` -> All rows returned

If I want to use `getAlbum($personalnummer)` -> Could not find row 1

Yes, there is an entry with Personalnummer 1 in the database and it is type int. The only difference is that, I use a Microsoft SQL Server, but the Configuration is right because all rows could be returned.

Any ideas?

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();

    return $resultSet;
}

public function getAlbum($personalnummer)
{
    $personalnummer  = (int) $personalnummer;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('Personalnummer' => $personalnummer));

    $row = $rowset->current();

    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $personalnummer");
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Comment: Your column is named `Personalnummer´? What kind of data it holds?

Comment: Its a Int field

Answer (score 0):

try this if it helps replace

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('Personalnummer' => $personalnummer));
```

with this

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();    
$where->equalTo('Personalnummer', $personalnummer);

$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select($where)
```

Comment: Thanks, but Call to undefined method Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::where()

Comment: @stefen, the example provided should work, not sure why it is not fetching the row, check if the tableGateway is properly initialized and fetching data, I had updated the answer using the where class, hope it helps

Comment: Lieder auch nicht :((
Wenn ich select() ohne eine Bedingung mache findet er als ersten Eintrag "object(DbTables\Model\IntranetLoginsView)#193 (33) { ["Personalnummer"]=> int(106) ["Anrede"]=> string(4) "Herr", blablablabl". Selbst wenn ich jetzt aber nach der Personalnummer 106 suche kommt die selbe Fehlermeldung. Bei suche nach ("Anrede" => "Herr") selbiges..